# Multiple HTML/CSS only sliders on one page not changing independently

Tags: html, css, ghost-blog

I am writing a blog post for a friend of mine, on the ghost platform. This blog post is going to be a very long post about multiple different objects, each requiring their own image slider. I'd like to re-use the same CSS for all 20 or so sliders on the page, only changing the html. 
I followed a slider tutorial online, that created a html/css only slider, as Ghost doesnt support scripting in their individual blog posts.

Unfortunately, when i click on one thumbnail, the image in all the other sliders disapears, and is only shown in that particular slider, making scrolling down the page a very boring experience.

Anyone able to spot the error? Here is an excerpt using only two sliders. take a look at the result further down:

```css
<style>
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {background: #ccc;}

.slider{
 width: 640px; 
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 320px; 
 margin: 100px auto;
 box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.slider>img{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0; top: 0;
 transition: all 0.2s;
}

.slider input[name='slide_switch'] {
 display: none;
}

.slider label {
 margin: 18px 0 0 18px;
 border: 3px solid #999;
 float: left;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 opacity: 0.6;
}

.slider label img{
 display: block;
}

.slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label {
 border-color: #666;
 opacity: 1;
}
.slider input[name='slide_switch'] ~ img {
 opacity: 0;
 transform: scale(1.1);
}
.slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label+img {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: scale(1);
}
</style>
```

```html
**The xx: **
Insert image
About 
Gallery of the xx

<div class="slider">
 <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id1"/>
 <label for="id1">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/3yiC6Yq.jpg" width="100"/>
 </label>
 <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/3yiC6Yq.jpg"/> 
 <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id2"/>
 <label for="id2">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/40Ly3VB.jpg" width="100"/>
 </label>
 <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/40Ly3VB.jpg"/>
 <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id3"/>
 <label for="id3">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg" width="100"/>
 </label>
 <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg"/>
 <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id4"/>
 <label for="id4">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/2rT2vdx.jpg" width="100"/>
 </label>
 <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/2rT2vdx.jpg"/>
 <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id5"/>
 <label for="id5">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg" width="100"/>
 </label>
 <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg"/>
</div>

**The yy**
Insert image
About 
Gallery of the yy

<div class="slider">
 <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id6"/>
 <label for="id6">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/3yiC6Yq.jpg" width="100"/>
 </label>
 <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/3yiC6Yq.jpg"/> 
 <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id7"/>
 <label for="id7">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/40Ly3VB.jpg" width="100"/>
 </label>
 <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/40Ly3VB.jpg"/>
 <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id8"/>
 <label for="id8">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg" width="100"/>
 </label>
 <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg"/>
 <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id9"/>
 <label for="id9">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/2rT2vdx.jpg" width="100"/>
 </label>
 <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/2rT2vdx.jpg"/>
 <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id10"/>
 <label for="id10">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg" width="100"/>
 </label>
 <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your radio buttons have the same name, so they're all considered a part of the same group. Only one radio button can be active in any one group. **Each group should have a different name** so they are grouped separately. Doing so will affect your current CSS but changing your [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) from `name=` to `name^=` or `name*=` will allow you to give each radio button set a different name. In the example below, we appended `_1` to the second set.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.slider {
  width: 640px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 320px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.slider>img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.slider input[name^='slide_switch'] {
  display: none;
}

.slider label {
  margin: 18px 0 0 18px;
  border: 3px solid #999;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.slider label img {
  display: block;
}

.slider input[name^='slide_switch']:checked+label {
  border-color: #666;
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider input[name^='slide_switch']~img {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.slider input[name^='slide_switch']:checked+label+img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch_1" id="id1" checked>
  <label for="id1">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/3yiC6Yq.jpg" width="100">
 </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/3yiC6Yq.jpg">
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch_1" id="id2">
  <label for="id2">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/40Ly3VB.jpg" width="100">
 </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/40Ly3VB.jpg">
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch_1" id="id3">
  <label for="id3">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg" width="100">
 </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch_1" id="id4">
  <label for="id4">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/2rT2vdx.jpg" width="100">
 </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/2rT2vdx.jpg">
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch_1" id="id5">
  <label for="id5">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg" width="100">
 </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg">
</div>

<div class="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id6" checked>
  <label for="id6">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/3yiC6Yq.jpg" width="100">
 </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/3yiC6Yq.jpg">
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id7">
  <label for="id7">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/40Ly3VB.jpg" width="100">
 </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/40Ly3VB.jpg">
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id8">
  <label for="id8">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg" width="100">
 </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id9">
  <label for="id9">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/2rT2vdx.jpg" width="100">
 </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/2rT2vdx.jpg">
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id10">
  <label for="id10">
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg" width="100">
 </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg">
</div>
```